# How to manage 2 UITableView (master and detail) in 1 UIView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, storyboard, master-detail

I would like to display 2 `UItableView` on a same `UIView`. Important thing: when I select a row on the first table (`master`), I want to display the detail rows on the second table (`detail`).

In order to do that, I have :

- created 1 `UIViewController` with 2 `UITableView` IB Outlet properties, linked with the 2 tables in the storyboard
- set delegate and datasource for both `UITableView` in the root `UIViewController`
- created 1 `UITableViewController` for each `UITableView`
- implemented all the required methods for both delegates

I manage to display data in the first table, but not in the second, although the *`tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`* is correct for the two tables.

When I run my app in debug mode, I don't see any call to the *`tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`* method for the detail table.

I don't understand what I have missed or where I'm wrong. Anyone could help me ?

Here are parts of my code :

### RootViewController.h

```
@interface RootViewController : UIViewController 
{
    MasterTVController * masterController;
    IBOutlet UITableView * masterTV;
    IBOutlet UITableView * detailTV;
}
```

### RootViewController.m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    if (masterController == nil) {
        masterController = [[masterTVController alloc] init];
    }
    [masterTV setDataSource:masterController];
    [masterTV setDelegate:masterController];
    masterController.view = masterController.tableView;

    [detailTV setDataSource:masterController.detailTVController];
    [detailTV setDelegate:masterController.detailTVController];
}
```

### MasterTVController.h

```
@interface MasterTVController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
{
    NSMutableArray * masterArray;
    NSMutableArray * detailArray;
    DetailTVController * detailTVController;
}
```

### MasterTVController.m

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        self.detailTVController = [[DetailTVController alloc] init];
        self.detailTVController.view = self.detailTVController.tableView;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.detailArray = [[self.masterArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"details"];
    self.detailTVController.dataArray = detailArray;
    [self.detailTVController.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Posting some of your code often helps people understand your issue.

Comment: I have posted some code to show the way I wanted to manage the two tables.

Comment: I don't see any code to initialize the `detailTVController` property of `MasterTVController`.

Comment: I have added the init method for the MasterTVController

Comment: How does `masterController.tableView` get connected to the master table view in the storyboard?  How does `detailTVController.tableView` get connected to the detail table view in the storyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your `detailTVController.tableView` is not set to `detailTV`, so that last line in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is not sending `reloadData` to the right table view.  Try adding this in `viewDidLoad`:

```
masterController.detailTVController.tableView = detailTV;
```

You might also need to set `masterController.tableView` in a similar fashion.

Also, one of these two lines seems suspicious:

```
[menusTV setDataSource:masterController];
[masterTV setDelegate:masterController];
```

Comment: It already works fin for the `master` table. I'm going to try your suggestion tonight, by modifying the `viewDidLoad` method for the `RootViewController`.  
  But something seems strange for me ; the `detailTVController` is allocated and initialized in the `initWithStyle` method for the `MasterViewController`, so after your suggested code ; will it work and why ?

Comment: I have modified my post for the last part of your comment, because there was an error. In the `RootViewController`, I set the datasource and the delegate for the two table which are `IBOutlet` properties of the `RootViewController`. Isn't it the good way to do that ?

Comment: The way you are setting `detailTV.delegate` and `detailTV.dataSource` is fine.

Comment: You said "It already works fin for the `master` table."  You never use `masterController.tableView` in the code you posted.  You do use `detailTVController.tableView`.  You don't assign to either one in the code you posted.  Not assigning `detailTVController.tableView` is a problem because you use it.  Maybe you use `masterController.tableView` in some other code that you did not post.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I don't really know where my mind was when I wrote this part of the code. I just modified the code for method `viewDidLoad` in the **`RootViewCntroller`** that way to make it work.
`masterController.detailTVController.tableView = self.detailTV;`
Something is still strange for me ; I didn't do something similar for the master tableView, and it works :
`masterController.tableView = self.masterTV;`

Comment: It doesn't matter what `masterController.tableView` is set to unless you use it somewhere.  You use `detailTVController.tableView` when you send the `reloadData` message to it.